# revision control for many unrelated files

Tags: matlab, mercurial

I'm curious to get people's thoughts on how to manage version control for unrelated functions in Matlab.

I keep a reasonably large set of general purpose scripts, each of which is more or less independent of the others.  I've been keeping them all in a single directory, containing a single repository in Mercurial.  I'm starting to collaborate much more, and I'd like my collaborators to be able modify the files, commit, branch, and merge.

The problem is that the files are independent of one another.  Essentially, they're like many separate little projects.  But Mercurial treats the repository as a single entity.  So if a collaborator modifies file A and B, and I only want to merge in the changes from file A, things get complicated.  I know that I could merge from the collaborator, then revert file B, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to handle this setup.

I could set up many tiny repositories to manage each file separately, but that also gets complicated.

I'm open to changing version control systems (although I like Mercurial a lot).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why does many repositories get complicated?

Answer (score 1):

It is considered a best practice to check in code after each bug fix/feature addition/or what not.  Given your files are really independent "projects" it seems unlikely a bug or feature would span multiple files.  Probably the best you can do is encourage your colleagues in best practices to commit changes only for a single file at once.  Explain that better discipline about checking in leads to more manageable source control later.  Hopefully you can get most to follow the practice and the few obstinate ones just stop taking their commits for.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your typical reasons for merging one change but not the other.  If you're using it to create a software *configuration*, i.e. sometimes you want to use version 1 of file A and version 2 of file B and sometimes it's the other way around, then you probably want to use subrepos to hold each file.  If it's because you never want to accept part of a collaborator's change, then they need to be instructed how to make their changes more cohesive and submit them separately.  That can sometimes be a difficult concept for people who either haven't used source control before, or who are accustomed to source control like svn that has little or no intrinsic concept of a changeset.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you want to maintain a single 'master' version of the files, merging in changes that you like and ignoring others. If collaborators want to develop other branches, then they should perhaps clone the repository, and you can then accept the changesets that you want in the master.

If you want to veto changes by other collaborators, then the changes either need to be kept separate (via a cloned repository or branch) or you need a review process before changes are pushed back to the trunk.

Answer (score 0):

I always use *incoming* repositories for collaborators. They match what the other person has made, but it avoids messing with my own repository. When you do this, you can then cherrypick their new changesets into your own repository with the **transplant** extension.